# class not found for DomPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf, classnotfound, laravel-dompdf, barryvdh

I am facing "use of unknown class" error when I am using the alias created for facades :: class in my controller.

```
$pdf = PDF ::loadView('test', $data);
```

This line says PDF is unknown class.
I have created alias in `app.php` as

```
  'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class,
```

I tried updating composer, clearing cache, config, etc. doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the full code involved? Why not use a common `use` statement, as you would do in other parts of PHP?

Comment: remember to use `use` and `composer dump-autoload` after adding a new package. also, the extra space on `PDF ::loadView` is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

you should not duplicate the code, if you look at the `composer.json` of the package you will see `extra.laravel.aliases` which will add to the list itself. the framework took care of that.

```php
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
        },
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\ServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Pdf": "Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\Facade\\Pdf",
                "PDF": "Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\Facade\\Pdf"
            }
        }
    },
```

### You need to take actions:

1. `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`
2. `use Barryvdh/DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;`
3. `$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);`

### To make sure you've installed everything correctly, you can run

1. `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`.
2. `rm bootstrap/cache/packages.php`.
3. `composer dump`.